# String manipulation into two parts in PHP

Tags: php

Can someone suggest a simple function that will parse a string into two parts, based on everything before and after the comma?  I want to split up a latitude longitude pair so that I have two variables instead of one.

I need to turn this:

> -79.5310706,43.6918950

into this:

> -79.531070
>   43.6918950

Comment: Google is your friend: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$parts = explode(",", "-79.5310706,43.6918950");
echo $parts[0];
// -79.5310706

echo $parts[1];
// 43.69189506
```

Or if you need it to stay as a space-separated string, just `str_replace()` the comma to a space!

```
echo str_replace(",", " ", "-79.5310706,43.6918950");
// -79.531070 43.6918950
```